# send data via serialised array

Tags: javascript, php, forms

i am trying to send data to the server using a serialised array but for a reason I cannot figure out it does not work at all.
I have input text fields and the following cod

```
$person =array ();
if(isset($_POST['first_name']))  {array_push($person,$_POST['first_name']);}
```

the hidden input field looks like this

```
<input type = "hidden" name = "collect" value = "<?php serialise($persons)?>">
```

The php code is as follows

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){$my_person = unserialise ($persons)}?>
```

I do not know why but it seems first of all that data does not get pushed into the array and secondly unserialised does not work there is an error that says bool(false). Please could you help me?

Comment: Why would you send Serialized data?  Also It's unserialize(with a z)

Comment: you have two variables `$person` and `$persons`

Comment: i send it to the server side and I thought I had to serialise it since it is an array. Please do you have a better idea Farkie?

Comment: Thanks Ramraider and sorry for the typo here in my code it is correct

Comment: i am still a beginner when it comes to php is it possible to snd the array without serializing it Farkie ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `echo` to put value in input

```
<input type = "hidden" name = "collect" value = "<?php echo serialise($persons)?>">
```

Comment: Thanks a million Rishi. Now I have a second problem This is what I get as a result of var_dump instead of the value of the field array(0) { }. Does this means the array is till empty?

Comment: what your getting in `echo $persons` ? in php code ?

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wampp\files\process.php on line 11
Array

Comment: you must share line no. 11 or better all code in process.php

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$my_person = unserialize($_POST['collect']) ;
var_dump($my_person);
}

Comment: be sure you are getting right value in `$_POST['collect']` as string serialised value.

Comment: How can I check that please?

Comment: what exactly you are gettingin `$_POST['collect']` ?

Comment: when I try to see what is inside of the array after pressing submit :  `echo $_POST['collect'];` This is what I get  `a:0:{}`

Comment: does the place where I put the hidden filed play a role in this? Because for some reason  the elements do not get pushed into the array. maybe I should have been more precise and say that I have three different forms and that I inserted the hidden field  in the same form containing the submit button to collect data from all other input fields in the two other forms.

Comment: okay so problem should be here `if(isset($_POST['first_name']))  {array_push($person,$_POST['first_name']);}` please check step by step to recognize the reason. you are in the best place.
`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Stay blessed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using different variables for accessing `persons`. Either use `person` or `persons`. Please check the below edited code

```
$persons =array (); //Either use `person` or `persons`
if(isset($_POST['first_name']))  {array_push($persons,$_POST['first_name']);} //Either use `person` or `persons`

// For text field name given as `personsarr`
<input type = "hidden" name = "personsarr" value = "<?php echo serialise($persons)?>">

<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){$my_person = unserialise ($personsarr)}?>
```